# Japanese Characters Registering As Gibberish

Tags: html, utf, cjk

I have the language pack for Japanese characters installed onto my computer so I can practice but when I put it into an html file and uploaded it to the server that I'm using, it displays as this weird gibberish.

The encoding is in utf-8 but it still appears this way?

http://kotonii.com/katakana.html

Comment: I read the source code of katakana.html and noticed that it only contains <html> tag and your contents is in it. It is not a right way to be as a html document. Add <head> tag under <html> tag, then you can use the answer provided by Leo K below. Also add <body> tag under <html> tag, which is where you can put your content. In addition, I guess you want to have a single japanese letter in each line. then, newline in html is <br> tag, where there are many other tags as well for that purpose though. you seems to be a beginner in html. Find some html quick start tutorial first. good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should check your server configuration. It does not have a "charset" in the "Content-type" header and in absence of this, the browser will use its own default charset (usually iso-8859-1, a.k.a. 'Latin1').

Your server has this:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

It should be this, for your browser to decode it as utf-8:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

You can also add this to the page's <head> section, it helps if you are viewing it in the browser as a local file (but shouldn't be a substitute for the HTTP header):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```